# Websocket, header and ranking

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, websocket

I'm trying to call an external websocket server but it doesn't work, i have the error : nonzero hanshake.

I'm using the client of superwebsocket in a c# app.

I compared (using wireShark) what i send with an example who works (but in javascript) and i see that the only difference is the ranking of the fields in the header.

Could be this the reason of my problem ? Should i respect the rank of the fields ?

PS : I send in this order

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Up grade
Sec-WebSocket-Key1:  DC1M 5VEEm 731
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 7 tQG6 7540Q226
Host: 127.0.0.1
Origin: 127.0.0.1
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: myProtocol
```

and what the javascript send :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Origin:  null
Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 3O45   82 4   ;Q 0 376
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key2: <361      6  W 12 Z152
Upgrade: WebSocket
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: myProtocol
```

Thanks !

Comment: there seem to be more differences than just the ranking of the fields in the header... for instance the "Connection" value is different, as is the "Origin", and also the "Host" seems to be using different ports between the two versions.  Do any of these changes make a difference?

Comment: The space in "Connection: Up grade" would cause handshake to fail it it isn't a typo

Comment: What variant(s) of the websocket protocol does your server understand?  The handshake is for the older Hixie variant; this is deprecated and has been replaced by the incompatible Hybi version in many uses.

Comment: thanks for your comments, for the Connection field i don't have a space between Up grade it was a mistake :). the protocol that i use is the hybi-00.

Comment: Here is the complete error message : seem to be serving, mode is 0
libwebsocket_parse sees parsing complete
nonzero handshake remainder
libwebsocket_close_and_free_session: just_kill_connection
not calling back closed due to old_state=1

Comment: To be sure i succeed to change the order of the sended fields but the result is always negative !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header fields are not ordered. From the websocket protocol, draft 17:

> ```
>    After the leading line in both cases come an unordered set of header
>    fields.  The meaning of these header fields is specified in Section 4
>    of this document.  Additional header fields may also be present, such
>    as cookies [RFC6265].  The format and parsing of headers is as
>    defined in [RFC2616].
> ```

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17

Comment: you have reason, i checked also the websocket protocol hybi-00 and it's mentionned that the order is not meaningful